# How to project a vector on a set defined by linear inequality constraints through KKT conditions?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, projection, karush-kuhn-tucker

I need to find the projection $x \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ of a vector $z \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ on the set defined by $Y \cdot x \geq 0$ where $Y$ is a (given but no specific property) matrix of size $m \cdot k$.

I first build the Lagrangian as follows :

$$L=\frac{1}{2} ||x-z||^2 -\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i Y(i,:)x$$ and set its gradient w.r.t. $x$ to $0$ which leads to $$x=z+\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i Y(i,:)^T$$

The inequality constraints adds an additional KKT condition :

$$\lambda_i \cdot Y(i,:)x=0 \; \forall i=1,...,m ; \lambda_i \geq 0$$

Replacing $x$ inside gives $$\lambda_i \cdot Y(i,:)[z+\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i Y(i,:)^T]=0 \; \forall i=1,...,m$$

It is where it becomes harder for me. I guess that either $\lambda_i$ or $Y(i,:)[z+\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i Y(i,:)^T]$ should be equal to $0$ but then I am stuck. Indeed, the second condition is a scalar product linking all the $\lambda_i$ and I don't know how to deal with it properly.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are right (up to indices relabeling), either $Y(i,:)[z+\sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j Y(j,:)^T]=0$ or $\lambda_i=0$ for any $i$, Let $\mathcal S=\left\lbrace i : Y(i,:)[z+\sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j Y(j,:)^T]=0 \right\rbrace$, then 
\begin{align*}
x = z + \sum_{i\in\mathcal S} \lambda_i Y(i,:)^T
\end{align*}
This satisfies the KKT conditions and is your solution. You cannot get a nicer form except if $Y$ is composed of orthogonal columns or have similar conditions.

Solving for the $\lambda$ parameters requires you to solve the system of $|\mathcal S|$ linear equations
\begin{align*}
Y(i,:)[z+\sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j Y(j,:)^T]=0&&\text{for } i\in\mathcal S
\end{align*}
So it is some self loop argument. But solving those equations is numerically easy and can be done efficiently if the matrix $Y$ have some structure.

Comment: Yes, but how do you compute the $\lambda_j$ that are in the sum?

Comment: See my edit, basically you have to solve the corresponding linear equations which looks like a self loop but in the end the problem is simpler.

Comment: What I thought doing is to solve $Y(i,:)[z+\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i Y(i,:)^T]=0$ for any $i$ which is a linear system of $m$ unknown (the $\lambda_j$). But in this case, I did not consider the case where $\lambda_i=0$ and I even have no guarantee that the $\lambda_i\geq 0$

Comment: thanks but please see my further comment. Still in trouble. How do I know a priori which $\lambda_i$ need to be set to $0$ ?

Comment: Yes $\lambda_i\geq 0$ is given by the KKT conditions (you can check it on the wikipedia page). So separating the $\lambda_i=0$ from $\lambda_i>0$ permits you to have the equations well defined even when dividing by $\lambda_i$. For your second question, $\lambda_i=0$ for any $i\notin\mathcal S$

Comment: How do I know a priori which λ_i need to be set to $0$ ?

Comment: If $i\notin\mathcal S$, $\lambda_i=0$

Comment: How to guarantee that the system of equations does not give me negative values of $\lambda_i$ ? Isn't there a way to proceed with dual form (not familiar at all with it though)

Comment: If any $\lambda_i$ is negative, then your set of inequalities is not feasible.